# Xcopy or robocopy batch file

Tags: xcopy, robocopy

I'm trying to create a batch file that takes latest `.exe`s   between dates format `DDMMYYYY` from a network drive and give it to all PCs with overwrite and skip if a pc is turned off.

Tried it with 1 file without date on 1 pc and succeeded but struggling with multiple.

Comment: So, what are you struggling with? What does the current script look like, what is failing? Some more details would be nice.

Comment: You need to ask an actual question.